# «Чего ты хочешь?» или «Что ты хочешь?»

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: «Чего ты хочешь?» или «Что ты хочешь?»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустимы оба варианта.

В некоторых случаях один из вариантов может быть более предпочтителен. Например, в ситуации неопределённости/неоднозначности зачастую уместнее вариант "чего ты хочешь?":

> — Чего ты хочешь? — спрашивает Виктор. — Погоди, погоди. Я не спрашиваю тебя, кем ты хочешь стать. Этого ты можешь еще не знать. Но чего ты хочешь? (Василий Аксёнов.)

В случае же вполне определённого выбора вопрос "что ты хочешь?" выглядит более предпочтительным:

> — Что ты хочешь? Морс или молоко? (Екатерина Вильмонт.)

Впрочем, разница здесь небольшая. Вполне возможно, что мои предпочтения субъективны.